# OAuth 2 for moving files on Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

About a year ago, I wrote a bot, which wrote out photos from Google photos in folders using google drive API. This script created folders with years and months. It was convenient because they could be downloaded easily. Then I used an OAuth authorization, and I had no problems. At the moment, I can't do this. As far as I understand, the rules have tightened, and you need to send the application for review. This requires a separate site on which I will have a privacy page and so on. I do not understand what the problem is, I do not pretend to touch other people's files. I want to use the API for my purposes and my account. A year ago, I just wrote localhost (for the redirect link). Now it is impossible. I found this method, https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices
but it has not permissions for moving files. Uploading only. Please help me. There must be some other way. I just need to get access to my google drive files via API, without any stupid checks. I do not have a separate site, I do not have an application for everyone. This is just a console script for me, but now it cannot pass authorization with rights for file moving.

Comment: Is this for moving files to other folder or other Google Drive account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out on my own. The fact is that in order to use api, it is not necessary to wait for approval of a specific permit (in my case is google drive permit). For your own account, there are not even any warnings, and for someone else's account, when authorization is passed, the system suppresses that the application has not yet passed validation. That's all.
And if you're interested in my application for moving photos in date folders, then here it is: https://github.com/devXpro/google-photo-bot